# Android: Async Task Thread Sleep Error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-sleep

have a first question in my career in stackoverflow. I hope that are you help me.

What's happen:

I have Fragment where i want to set some recyclerView with some dates, it worked until I wanted to do ProgressDialog with some ErrorMgs.

This is my onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    textViewErrorMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message);
    progressBarLoading = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pb_loading);
    new TakeDates().execute();
    return view;
}
```

I add AsyncTask:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class TakeDates extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading places...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2200);
            populateFromJson();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

And the last method is populateFromJson:

```
 private void populateFromJson() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    assert conMgr != null;
    NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (i != null && i.isConnected() && i.isAvailable()) {
        ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService(PLACES_URL);

        Call<PlaceList> call = api.getMyJSON();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<PlaceList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PlaceList> call, Response<PlaceList> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    itemList = response.body().getItemList();
                    adapter = new RecyclerViewPlaceAdapter(itemList, getContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    showPlaces();
                } else {
                    showErrorMessage("Try to restart your app.");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PlaceList> call, Throwable t) {
                showErrorMessage("Here is the main error: " + t.getMessage() + "\nTry to restart your app.");
            }
        });
    } else {
        showErrorMessage("Internet Connection Not Available" + "\nTry to find better connection to the internet.");
    }
}
```

Now about Errors:
1) **Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

I understand that the main part of the Error is here:

**After added SLEEP Make ERROR**

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2200); 
            populateFromJson();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is the onResponse method running in the UI thread (I don't think so).  If it is not, the you cannot do anything with `recyclerView` in that method.

Comment: In the onResponse() callback of your Retrofit call you are calling methods of recyclerView. View related methods can be called from Main Thread but in your case onResponse method will get executed in the AsyncTask. 

P.S. Why did you create an async task in the first place, the enqueue method of the Retrofit call will get executed in a background thread. No need to put it in the Async task.

Comment: @RohanArora I need the Async task for progress dialog. After some projects and some tutorials i make coclusion that the Aync task fo that is better...If im not wirte, can you suggest something to me? Thanks!

Comment: @PavelPetkevich No need to create to create AsyncTask for Progress Dialogs. Just call progressDialog.show() just before call.enqueue() and progressDialog.dimiss() in onResult() and onFailure() callbacks.

Comment: @PavelPetkevich ProgressDialogs are now deprecated in API 26 and above.

Comment: @RohanArora Thanks, you're right, but infact no ive a good expirience with AsyncTask&Enqueue and how NOT use it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`populateFromJson()` try to use `recicleView`. View (and View subclasses) Object cannot be used from any thread except the Activity thread.

When you do `.execute()` on your AsyncTask `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` will be executed by the activity thread and `doInBackground` by a child Thread.

Once you get this it will be easy for you to understand that to avoid that error you should call `populateFromJson()` in `onPostExecute`

N.B. if your doInBackground method really needs to do just a wait there are more efficent way to do this. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948791/what-is-fast-wait-notify-or-busy-wait-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882611/how-to-make-a-delayed-non-blocking-function-call)

Comment: Ok, thats mean that i should to call populateFromJson() in onPostExecute(), in doInBackground only threadSleep. Or all make in doInBackground (without populateFromJson() ), is it correct ?:)

Comment: yeah. The usual pattern is this: onPreExecute to get data from view, doInBackground to do heavy calculation with those data and onPostExecute to show results in views.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)). It's a way to show the user the progress, for example using a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! Is it work for me, ill try to make this better if its possible with your suggest link!

Answer (score 0):

No, the root cause of error is that you are trying to work with views form worker thread.
Should get your call's result inside this method

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
  //work with you RecyclerView here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use an AsyncTask. Just call `populateFromJson()` in onCreateView().

Comment: @greenapps i was read that AsyncTask(their control doInBackground, onPreExecute , onPostExecute) is the best way if i want to work with progress Dialog...isnt it?

Comment: No. It is not i think. And would you want one?

Answer (score -1):

You can't update the view from a background thread, have your async task return the item list in doInBackground, onPostExecuted will receive the list as a parameter and from that method you can update the recycler view.

An easier way would be to replace async task with rxjava

Comment: Replacing a simple async task with a heavyweight library like rxjava is a horrible idea.

Comment: Just thought it will help with networking problem and since he is already using retrofit will make consuming the api easier,

Comment: Hi, @UmarKhattab have you got some Example for usage?

Comment: Checkout  [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792) tutorial, its pretty straightforward. The first approach used just retrofit and then rxJava and retrofit