# Is it possible to schedule a job with Spring @Scheduled annotation to run every hour but each time at random hour?

Tags: java, spring, random, schedule

I would like to run my task/method each hour.. but each time at random minute.
I've already tried [Spring @Scheduled to be started every day at a random minute between 4:00AM and 4:30AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016433/spring-scheduled-to-be-started-every-day-at-a-random-minute-between-400am-and) but this solution is setting random initial value but after that same minute is used.

I would like to achieve a situation where the job is running like this. ex:

8:10
9:41
10:12 
...

Comment: at least how many times you have to run the job per day and what should be delay time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, so...this **isn't** a schedule.  This is a non-deterministic event.

A **scheduled** event is something which is repeatable and something which can be consistently fired at a specific time.  There's an order and predictability which go hand-in-hand with this.

By having a job fire off at a given hour but not *necessarily* at a given minute, you lose predictability which is what the `@Scheduled` annotation would enforce (not necessarily through implementation, but as a side-effect; annotations may only contain compile-time constants and cannot dynamically change during runtime).

As for a solution, `Thread.sleep` is brittle and will cause your **entire** application to sleep for that period of time which ***isn't*** what you want to do.  Instead, [you could wrap your critical code in a non-blocking thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10882611/1079354) and schedule that instead.

**Warning:  Untested code below**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * ?")
public void executeStrangely() {
    // Based on the schedule above,
    // all schedule finalization should happen at minute 0.
    // If the pool tries to execute at minute 0, there *might* be
    // a race condition with the actual thread running this block.
    // We do *not* include minute 0 for this reason.
    Random random = new Random();
    final int actualMinuteOfExecution = 1 + random.nextInt(59);
    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    exec.schedule(() -> {
        // Critical code here
    }, actualMinuteOfExecution, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

I leave the effort of managing resources in a thread-safe manner as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good explanation.